# Zooming on a Canvasjs plot and displaying the Y-axis range

Tags: canvasjs

When zooming on a Canvasjs plot, how can one display the Y-axis value range selected by the cursor within the tooltip content? Simply put, I am interested in automatically displaying the value of the Y-axis minimum (Ymin) on the left and the value of the Y-axis maximum (Ymax) on the right selected by the cursor within the zoom window.

Also, how can one calculate the difference between Ymin and Ymax selected within the zoom window by the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

convertPixelToValue() method can be used to get the position of the cursor in Y axis.

- set display property of the two textbox(to be used as tooltip) to none.
- the mousedown event will be called when there is a mousedown event fired inside the plot area. And then the mousemove event will be fired on dragging the cursor. Which in turn will set the textbox to visible, and with the help of convertPixeToValue() y axis value would be shown in the textbox. And on mouseup the display properties of the textbox would be set to none.

Please go through this following jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p6dq37tt/

```
var yMinValue = jQuery("#yMinValue");
var yMaxValue = jQuery("#yMaxValue");
var y1, y2; //To assign the yMin and yMax value to calculate the difference
var dps = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   zoomEnabled: true,
   zoomType: "y",
   title: {
     text: "Preview y-values while zooming"
   },
   subtitles: [{
     text: "Click and drag to see the values"
   }],
   data: [{
     type: "line",
     dataPoints: dps
   }]
 });
 chart.render();

function mousemovehandler(e) {
   var parentOffset = jQuery(this).parent().offset();
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top

   var xValue = Math.round(chart.axisX[0].convertPixelToValue(relX));
   var yValue = Math.round(chart.axisY[0].convertPixelToValue(relY));

   y1 = yValue;

     var valueDiff = y1 - y2; //calculating the difference

   if(xValue >= chart.axisX[0].minimum || xValue <= chart.axisX[0].maximum) {
     yMinValue.css({
       left: e.pageX - 50,
       top: e.pageY - 20
     }); //assigning the position for the yMinValue

     jQuery("#yMinValue").val(yValue);
   }

   jQuery("#divDifference").val(Math.abs(valueDiff));
   jQuery("#yMaxValue").removeClass("textbox");          //removing the textbox class
   jQuery("#yMinValue").removeClass("textbox");
}

var parentElement = jQuery(".canvasjs-chart-toolbar");
var childElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

//for displaying the yMaxValue when the mousedown event is fired.
jQuery(".canvasjs-chart-canvas").last().on("mousedown", function(e) {
  if (childElement[0].getAttribute("state") === "pan") {  //checking whether the event trigger is zoom or pan.
    var parentOffset = jQuery(this).parent().offset();
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top
    var yValue = Math.round(chart.axisY[0].convertPixelToValue(relY));
    //assigning value of y2 used to calculate the difference.
    y2 = yValue;

    yMaxValue.css({
      left: e.pageX - 50,
      top: e.pageY - 20
    });
    yMinValue.css({
      left: e.pageX - 50,
      top: e.pageY - 20
    });

    //hidding the yMinValue behind the yMaxValue.
    var yvalue = document.getElementById("yMaxValue");
    yvalue.setAttribute("value", yValue);
    jQuery(".canvasjs-chart-canvas").last().on("mousemove", mousemovehandler);
  }
});

//To hide toolTips when mouse is released
jQuery(".canvasjs-chart-canvas").last().on("mouseup", function(e) {
  jQuery("#yMinValue").addClass("textbox");
  jQuery("#yMaxValue").addClass("textbox");
  jQuery(".canvasjs-chart-canvas").last().off("mousemove");
});

var xVal = 0;
var yVal = 15;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  yVal = yVal + Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5));
  dps.push({
    x: xVal,
    y: yVal
  });
  xVal++;
}
chart.render();
```